# REST API Design - POST different than GET

Tags: rest

I am designing a REST API where I have the following behavior of the resource:

For creating a resource, there is initial data should be sent, which is relevant only for creation.

Which means, that the `GET` resource representation is different than the `POST` one.

Example:

### POST

```
/api/customers

Request body:

{
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "creation_specific_data": "data"
}
```

### GET

```
/api/customers/1

Response body:

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe"
}
```

So, as you see, the data on `GET` will always be partial than the one upon creation.

From my understanding, it is acceptable to supply less properties in `POST` and upon `GET` you receive more data (e.g. *id* auto generated by the server).
The question, is it also acceptable the other way around? Supply more data upon `POST` and receive less data upon `GET`?

Comment: Yes why not? Get list of customers id and just name who have ordered something..

Comment: Here you mean that you can have selective fields on a resource, right? I mean that you never can get the "creation_specific_data" field, because it is not part of the resource after creation. (At least not part of the API).

Comment: yes why not. Not necessary you need every details of customer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had a hunch that this is acceptable, wanted to get other opinions also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you do with `POST` is acceptable, as long as it's not replicating functionality already standardized by other method -- like using `POST` for simple retrieval instead of `GET` -- and properly documented.